# Why won’t my Ubuntu download

Tags: kernel

When I try to install it it says

Ubuntu kernel [insert up address] pcieport 0000:000 ic.5s device [numbers] error status mask = 00000001/00020000
Same start [0] Receiver error  (first) 
Same start AER: Corrected error received id=numbers
Then it says it corrected it but it doesn’t install help install

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You weren't very specific as your question is worded more as a statement.  Did you verify your downloaded ISO was valid?   Refer to https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu.   If was checked and was valid, did `try ubuntu` work?  (we don't know what version of Ubuntu you're using, so I'm assuming it had 'try'..)  Did you download a version suitable for your hardware? (does the architecture match etc..  *the more details you provide us, the more we can skip these possibly unrelated questions..*)

Comment: It worked before now it says the installer crashed

Comment: If there is something wrong with the installer you are using; it may be inconsistent, which is why verifying the downloaded ISO is so necessary (45-60 secs to do it, instead of hours of problem-solving makes it good insurance) . The next step I mentioned is verifying the write-to-dvd-thumb-drive which can be done via tools (if your unspecified version has it) or the 'try'.   You haven't read, confirmed any done steps, or provided any more details...

Comment: The version is Ubuntu 18.04 and I will check the drive to see if it matches

Comment: Also yes try Ubuntu worked and I checked the drive for defects in grub and it didn’t come up with any